# XML Combing Duplicate IDs to a single XML and removing the duplicate

Tags: c#, xml, duplicates

I have an XML file with several customers. When the customer ID is duplicated, I want to take the service from the duplicate customer record and add it to the initial customer record. I'm trying to do this in C#.

So the following two records:

```
<customer ID="200054598540" phone="352-555-1234" name="PAULSON ROBERT">
    <services>
      <service type="Electric" premise="5000001234" priority="0" />
    </services>
    <customFields>
      <customField key="address" value="1521 NE 23RD AVE" />
      <customField key="connection" value="CONNECTED" />
    </customFields>
  </customer>
  <customer ID="200054598540" phone="352-555-1234" name="PAULSON ROBERT">
    <services>
      <service type="Water" premise="5000001235" priority="0" />
    </services>
    <customFields>
      <customField key="address" value="1521 NE 23RD AVE" />
      <customField key="connection" value="CONNECTED" />
    </customFields>
  </customer>
```

Become one, and it removes the duplicate, leading to:

```
  <customer ID="200054598540" phone="352-555-1234" name="PAULSON ROBERT">
    <services>
      <service type="Electric" premise="5000001234" priority="0" />
      <service type="Water" premise="5000001235" priority="0" />
    </services>
    <customFields>
      <customField key="address" value="1521 NE 23RD AVE" />
      <customField key="connection" value="CONNECTED" />
    </customFields>
  </customer>

private static void combineDuplicates()
{
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\customer_premise_osi_oms\customers.xml");
    var customers = doc.Descendants("customer").GroupBy(x => (string)x.Attribute("ID")).ToList();

    foreach (var customer in customers)
    {
        XElement firstAccount = customer.FirstOrDefault();
        XElement firstServices = firstAccount.Element("services");
        XElement firstCustomerField = firstAccount.Element("customFields");

        for (int i = customer.Count() - 1; i >= 1; i--)
        {
            XElement account = customer.Skip(i).FirstOrDefault();
            List<XElement> services = account.Descendants("service").ToList();
            firstServices.Add(services);
            //List<XElement> customFields = account.Descendants("customField").ToList();
            //firstCustomerField.Add(customFields);
            account.Remove();
        }
    }

    doc.Save(@"c:\customer_premise_osi_oms\customers_dupe.xml");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Xml Linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication75
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            var customers = doc.Descendants("customer").GroupBy(x => (string)x.Attribute("ID")).ToList();

            foreach (var customer in customers)
            {
                XElement firstAccount = customer.FirstOrDefault();
                XElement firstServices = firstAccount.Element("services");
                XElement firstCustomerField = firstAccount.Element("customFields");

                for (int i = customer.Count() - 1; i >= 1; i--)
                {
                    XElement account = customer.Skip(i).FirstOrDefault();
                    List<XElement> services = account.Descendants("service").ToList();
                    firstServices.Add(services);
                    List<XElement> customFields = account.Descendants("customField").ToList();
                    firstCustomerField.Add(customFields);
                    account.Remove();
                }
            }

        }

    }



}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I will give it a try and I think I understand how it works. I'm creating the xml doc from a csv, the turning around and using the xml doc to combine the duplicates so I didn't know if it was better to combine the duplicate account while parsing the csv, or after creating the xml. Again appreciate this.

Comment: It is hard to determine to remove duplicates from the csv or the xml.  Using the CSV you have to read the entire file and put data into an object that you can enumerate like List<List<string>>.  The CSV is more efficient because you can sort the list and then skip duplicates when the previous row match the current row.  You do not have to remove the duplicates.

Comment: Updated the op with the code. I added a doc.Save() and discovered that it is adding multiple custom fields for multiple services.

Comment: Okay I just commented out the two custom fields lines and it appears to be functioning correctly. I'm going to throw it up again the full list of customers to see if it breaks. Thanks again for the assistance.